# Mixing ARC with non-ARC generates EXC_BAD_ACCESS. How to fix?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, ios6, exc-bad-access

I am converting my iOS4 project to ARC. I am using some external libraries such as PTPasscodeViewController, AppPirater, Flurry. I keep reaching a EXC_BAD_ACCESS which means I am send a message to a deallocated object. I use Instruments to trace it but cannot figure out how to solve it. I'm hoping someone from SO can point me in the right direction.

My SettingsViewController is compiled with no ARC (-fno-obj-arc). It is initialized in my main root view controller called IouViewController:

```
-(void)showSettings:(id)sender {
    SettingsViewController *infoView = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
    [infoView setIouArray:iouTableArray];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:infoView animated:YES];
}
```

When I run the instrument, I see that this is the cause:

[image: Instrument image 1]

[image: Instrument image 2]

So, from image 2, I see that the release is from 'main.m'??? I am assuming it has something to do with the autorelease pool in main.m. So, one 'mistake' I made when I was converting to ARC is that I change the main.m to be the same as that of a new project with ARC-enabled. I am not sure if that makes any difference but I was having other EXC_BAD_ACCESS issues and doing that make it work.

For reference, here is my main.m:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([IouApp2AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

As an additonal note, when it crashes, it does jump to main.m with message "Thread 1: signal SIGKILL".

I don't know what I would do without SO. Thanks for all the help from the community.

UPDATE 1: If I try to use ARC for SettingsViewController, I get some errors that I am less than comfortable to deal with it. This is one example:

```
            // passcode is correct, direct to PasscodeSettingsViewController

            // self retain, autorelease might be needed so that you do not look access to where the navigationController is since we pop one
            [[self retain] autorelease];

            // if you set popViewControllerAnimated:YES, weird title things happen. DO NOT MESS!!!
            [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

This code snippet is from the PTPasscodeViewController example codebase. Using ARC, it gave me the error:

```
[rewriter] it is not safe to remove an unused 'autorelease' message; its receiver may be destroyed immediately
```

Comment: The ARC disabling compiler flag is `-fno-objc-arc` not `-fno-obj-arc`.

Comment: Have you used the static analyzer on all of your code, and all of the library source code?  Have you eliminated all of the static analyzer's warnings?

Comment: @Rob. Yes. I do use static analyzer but no I have not eliminated most of it. I am going through the files one by one and I don't want to make too many changes and won't be able to backtrack. A lot of the problem rise with the lib I am using and the view controller which uses the lib. But, it is tricky to change...

Comment: This is too ambiguous (and the problem has nothing to do with your `main`). You simply need to identify the offending line of code by either single-stepping through candidate routines (`showSettings`, the `SettingsViewController` `viewDidLoad`, etc.) or try [adding exception breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html)? That can help quickly identify the offending line of code. But the two provided snippets of code are unlikely to be source of problem.

Comment: @Rub. I have updated my question with more information on why I don't want to change the SettingsViewController. With regards to the static analyzer, the tool only complains on PTPasscodeViewController, which is the library, and that is what I mean when I said I do run static analyzer but didn't fix all the issues.

Comment: @Yko I don't know how we can help because neither this code nor the instruments screen snapshots are enough to diagnose what's going on. I can understand your reticence to invest time fixing the static analyzer issues, but it really doesn't make sense trying to track down bugs until you do. And it strikes me that once you have a clean bill of health from analyzer, you'll just have to stumble through, exception by exception, identifying the precise line that's causing the problem (either exception breakpoints or single step through candidate routines) and fixing the respective issue.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the comments so yea I will try to do that. What I was trying to say is that I have been fixing the issues that analyzer indicated except when it comes to code from the external libs that I use. And it is a can of worms if I go down that route. I mean I might as well write my own. To be fair, the lib is from 2010 and hasn't been updated. It is primary 2 sources which you add to your project.

Comment: @Yko if you're up for it, you could zip up your project and I (we) could take a look, but other than that, it's really hard for us to help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17476/discussion-between-rob-and-yko)

Comment: Every time the static analyser finds a problem, it really tells you "this _will_ go wrong eventually". There's no point in looking for bugs until you fixed all the problems that the static analyser shows you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are converting your project to ARC, you should enable ARC on all *your* code.  Xcode will give you errors in all the places where you're doing things like calling `autorelease`, `retain`, and `release`.  Just build, fix errors, build, fix errors...repeat until it builds successfully.  For any third-party code you're using, you should disable ARC.  For any third-party compiled libraries you're referencing, you should be able to use them normally.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226) for more information on the transition.

Comment: Well, that is the problem. Since the library that I am using involves initWithDelegate, if I try to use ARC for my SettingsViewController which uses the PasscodeViewController, it will crash.

Comment: @Yko - Why does that make it crash?

Comment: Jefferson. I have updated my question with additional info on why I don't enable ARC for one of my view controllers.